# php, MySQL - while looping and saving to record

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for a way to run this script through a table in my MySQL database.

1. Firstly, how do I define the table in which to loop this script?
2. How do I add the result of `get_httpcode` into another field in the
   record, 'imgstatus'?

Are there any better ways of approaching this?

```
<?php 

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

function get_httpcode($url) {
    $headers = get_headers($url, 0);
    // Return http status code
    return substr($headers[0], 9, 3);
  }

    while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)):

      $result = get_httpcode('http://'.$data['img']);   
      echo $data['img'].' = '.$result.'<br/>';

    endwhile;

?>
```

Comment: I think your code do nothing, there is no query executed, also running mysql_fetch_assoc over mysqli_connect if not possible

Answer (score 1):

1 - First you have to actually define a table to run your query like : create table tablename(...);

2 - Then you must write a sql query to get the data out of your table

3 - Then you have to define what $data is

4 - Then you should delete endwhile statement

5 - Then you should fix get_httpcode function because it will always return the 0th element in the header, most probably the http return code.

For simple examples, start with below:

1 - http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php

2 - http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql

Comment: Can you point me to any examples where something similar to my requirements has been created? Eager to learn J